# How to separate the local configs and the online configs : asp.net mvc app

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, web-config

Is it there (I'm sure there is) a way to separate the local Config file and the online ? I don't want to write and rewrite each time i upload my web.config files! talking about an asp.net mvc3  application!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using .NET 4.0, take a look at [Web.config Transformations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx)

It basically keeps a base web.config file, and then you can specify different values depending on whether you're in Release or Debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple solution is to have sections of your web.config reference external files. You can then change the external file without a need to restart the web application.
You can then overwrite the external file with one that contains data required for your local environment.

When you come to publish your app. you can include the online config files.